# Executing multiple java process on same VisualCode workspace

Tags: java, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, microservices

I have three springboot app in a visual Studio code workspace. All three configured to run on unique port.Is it possible to start all three springboot service on the same workspace? Earlier I have seen options where one can select the select the terminals for each process. Anysuggestion would be of great help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `launch.json` and [compound](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_compound-launch-configurations) the three projects.

1. Create a `launch.json`, which should generate configurations automatically.
2. Add `compound` args. Compound configurations list the names of the above three launch configuration.

   ```
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Compound",
            "configurations": ["Launch Demo1Application","Launch Demo2Application","Launch DemoApplication"]
        }
    ]
   ```

[image]

3. Select `compound` then debug.

See the effect in my VS Code:[image]

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @JamesStan. Glad my answer helps you. It's appreciated that you accept it to mark this question as resolved.